# Natural map of normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $N_1,N_2\vartriangleleft G$ two normal subgroups of the group $G$ with $N_1\subset N_2\subset G$. How do I prove that the natural map $G/N_1\rightarrow G/N_2$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $N_2/N_1=\{n_2N_1:n_2\in N_2\}$?

Comment: How comfortable are you with the natural map? As the name implies, the theorem should sort of 'show up' once you're familiar enough with the situation.

Comment: @pjs36 I don't see how it can suddenly show up, I know what the natural map is, but I can't understand what I'm supposed to do here

Comment: @Stan_Allen: First show that the map is well-defined; then show that the map is a homomorphism; then show that it is surjective. Finally show the claim about the kernel. Proceed step by step to get a better feeling for your task. At every step check your understanding of the definitions involved.

Comment: @Moritz what must I show, to prove that it's well-defined? (what does that mean?)

Comment: @Stan_Allen: Consider your map $\vartheta:G/N_1 \to G/N_2$ via $n N_1 \mapsto n N_2$. Then, "well-defined" means that $n N_1 = n' N_1$ implies $\vartheta(n N_1) = \vartheta(n' N_1)$. In detail: $n N_1 = n' N_1$ implies $n^{-1} * n \in N_1 \subseteq N_2$. Thus, $n N_2 = n' N_2$ and so $\vartheta(n N_1) = n N_2 = n' N_2 = \vartheta(n' N_1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The natural map is given by $gN_1 \mapsto gN_2$.  To show that the map is a well-defined homomorphism, we do the following: Let $\varphi : G \rightarrow G/N_2$ be the quotient map.  Since $N_1 \subset N_2 = \mathrm{ker} \varphi$, there exists a (well-defined!) homomorphism $\psi : G/N_1 \rightarrow G/N_2$ such that $\psi(gN_1) = \varphi(g) = gN_2$. Since $\varphi$ is surjective, so is $\psi$.

Finally, what's the kernel of $\psi$? Well, $\psi(gN_1) = 0$ precisely when $g \in N_2$ (recall that $0$ means the coset $N_2$.)  Thus, $\mathrm{ker} \psi = N_2/N_1$.